# Can you package multiple forge mods into a single jar?

Tags: minecraft-forge

When you are using Minecraft forge, it creates an external /mods/ folder that you place your mods in. Is there a way to package all the mods, configuration settings (like splash.propreties) and assets into a single .jar file for ease of distribution?

I am making a custom mod pack, and I don't like the fact that you have to install forge, then download the mod pack, then install the mods in order to run my mod pack. Is there a way to package it into a single jar so that you can just add it as a profile in the launcher and not have to do anything else?

I also need to be able to modify configuration files like splash.propreties, and I would like these to be packaged into the jar as well.

Note: I **do not** want to use premade launchers like Twitch or Technic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to package all of your mods into a single jar; there is such thing as a '[fat jar](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/)', but it's not what you're after. StackOverflow is [intended](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) more for code so you might find some more helpful advice over on the [Forge forums](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/).

That being said, you could utilise a [Self Extracting Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive) (SFX) such as [IExpress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress) or [7zip](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm) to package all of your mods into one, compressed, file which when executed can extract the mods into the right place. As for having one profile, as I'm sure you're aware, within your `/mods` directory, you can have another directory for profile-specific mods. So you could have your mods extract to a `/mods/modpackname/...` directory. Forge doesn't have great documentation but [this writeup](https://twnatelo.wordpress.com/2017/03/10/minecraft-how-to-install-different-and-separate-mods-for-multiple-profiles/) explains the process step by step.

Hope that helps