# Is there a way to add Forge Mods into a Forge client?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

So what i'm thinking is:

Instead of having a Mod in the external mods folder, is there a way to just package the whole thing in the client? Installing like 500 mods... not fun. Getting them all packed in as one jar (the client itself) with all the mods built in? Saves install time. A whole lot. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a jar full of your mods, the most user-friendly way to ship a lot of different mods is with a 'mod pack' for which there are a few supporting launchers, [Twitch](https://help.twitch.tv/s/article/guide-to-modpacks?language=en_US#Import) and [Technicpack](https://technicpack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204199345-How-to-make-a-Minecraft-modpack) are the more popular ones. The hyperlinks go to the respective 'How-To' guide on making a mod pack.

As I answered on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62721261/11916773) question, you can use a self-extracting archive to do the heavy lifting for the user if you don't want to use a launcher.